# how to add gravity forms to blog page(posts page) in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I using gravity forms plugin and I want to add a form in my blog page(posts page) but on the page editor, I can't add gravity form in the content.

Or I need to show the form where I need it, not in the content of the post or page

**my problems are:**

1. I can't(don't know how to) show the form where I want
2. I can't show my form inside blog page(posts page)

my `index.php` and `single.php` files code:

```
<?php
get_header();
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <article class="post page">
            
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile;
else:
    echo '<p>No Content Found!</p>';
endif; ?>

 <div class="gravity-form-place">
    <!-- gravity form must show here -->
 </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

how to show the forms inside `<div class="gravity-form-place">` in the `single.php` file ?

how to show the forms inside `<div class="gravity-form-place">` in the `index.php` file blog page(posts page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use Gravity Form shortcode? If you haven't, try it. Here's the documentation:

[Creating a Form Shortcode - Gravity Form](https://docs.gravityforms.com/shortcodes/)

It should be something like this:

```
<?php 

    echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1"]' );

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you created your form you should be able to get a short code. Copy it and paste it in between the following

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('_Your_Short_Code_Goes_Here_'); ?>
```

The just paste that line in between your div:

```
<div class="gravity-form-place">
<!-- gravity form must show here -->
<?php echo do_shortcode('_Your_Short_Code_Goes_Here_'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be outputting the form via PHP, the best way to do so is with the `gravity_form()` function.

```php
gravity_form( 1, false, false, false, '', false );
```

Full details here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/adding-a-form-to-the-theme-file/#function-call